# Speed of mysql query on tables containing blob depends on filesystem cache

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, blob

I have a table with approximately 120k rows, which contains a field with a BLOB (not more than 1MB each entry in size, usually much less). My problem is that whenever I run a query asking any columns on this table (*not* including the BLOB one), if the filesystem cache is empty, it takes approximately 40'' to complete. All subsequent queries on the same table require less than 1'' (testing from the command line client, on the server itself). The number of rows returned in the queries vary from an empty set to 60k+

I have eliminated the query cache so it has nothing to do with it. 
The table is myisam but I also tried to change it to innodb (and setting ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT), but without any luck.

If I remove the BLOB column, the query is always fast.

So I would assume that the server reads the blobs from the disk (or parts of them) and the filesystem caches them. The problem is that on a server with high traffic and limited memory, the filesystem cache is refreshed every once in a while, so this particular query keeps causing me trouble.

So my question is, is there a way to considerably speed things up, without removing the blob column from the table?

here are 2 example queries, ran one after the other, along with explain, indexes and table definition:

```
mysql> SELECT ct.score FROM completed_tests ct where ct.status != 'deleted' and ct.status != 'failed' and score < 100;
Empty set (48.21 sec)
mysql> SELECT ct.score FROM completed_tests ct where ct.status != 'deleted' and ct.status != 'failed' and score < 99;
Empty set (1.16 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT ct.score FROM completed_tests ct where ct.status != 'deleted' and ct.status != 'failed' and score < 99;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | ct    | range | status,score  | status | 768     | NULL | 82096 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show indexes from completed_tests;
+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| completed_tests |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |      583938 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | users_login |            1 | users_LOGIN | A         |       11449 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | tests_ID    |            1 | tests_ID    | A         |         140 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | status      |            1 | status      | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | timestamp   |            1 | timestamp   | A         |      291969 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | archive     |            1 | archive     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | score       |            1 | score       | A         |         783 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |
| completed_tests |          1 | pending     |            1 | pending     | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
+-----------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+

mysql> show create table completed_tests;
+-----------------+--------------------------------------
| Table           | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
+-----------------+--------------------------------------
| completed_tests | CREATE TABLE `completed_tests` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `users_LOGIN` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tests_ID` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `test` longblob,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `archive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_start` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_end` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_spent` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `pending` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_login` (`users_LOGIN`),
  KEY `tests_ID` (`tests_ID`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `archive` (`archive`),
  KEY `score` (`score`),
  KEY `pending` (`pending`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=117996 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I originally posted this on [mysql query slow at first fast afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409518/mysql-query-slow-at-first-fast-afterwards) but I now have more information so I repost as a different question
I also posted this on the [mysql forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,517931,517931#msg-517931), but I haven't heard back

Thanks in advance as always

Comment: +1 well-written, complete question. I hope you get a good answer (I got nothin' :-)  If you get an answer on the mysql forum and nobody answers here, please post the answer (as an answer below), wait the requisite 48 hours, and then accept it. You won't get points but it'll show up as an answered question for other people searching on this topic.  Good luck.

Comment: Can't answer "why" part. I can suggest you don't care about that. OK, you know your first query is slow. So what? Any subsequent queries are fast, as I understood. So knowing that build your application knowing this fact. Add "warmup" stage at some point, for example when customer has to type in characters into login form. And like that... It's better than to play with cache settings.

Comment: And here is an example how google solves same issue, [http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Warmup_Requests](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances.html#Warmup_Requests).

Comment: it's not only the first query that's slow, it happens whenever the system memory availability is low

Comment: Oh " are minutes? I thought you're talking about seconds here... Just ignore my comments.

Comment: no, it is seconds. But 40 seconds for a query that runs relatively often is unacceptable. Plus, I'm hoping for an enlightening solution that will make me a better person (or better developer anyway)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was doing research on this issue for a while. Many people recommend using blob with only one primary key in a separate table and storing the blobs meta data in another table with a foreign key to the blob table. With this the performance will be higher considerably.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I decided to do after all, but I haven't tested it yet on real world scenarios to post here.

Comment: yep, that's what I did eventually and the performance issue was fixed. I still had to edit countless lines of code though, I was hoping for a pure database table restructure but that turned out more difficult than I could manage.

Answer (score 25):

The design of BLOB (=TEXT) storage in MySQL seems to be totally flawed and counter-intuitive. I ran a couple of times into the same problem and was unable to find any authoritative explanation. The most detailed analysis I've finally found is this post from 2010: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

General belief and expectation is that BLOBs/TEXTs are stored outside main row storage (e.g., see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811334/1202674)). This is NOT TRUE, though. There are several issues here (I'm basing on the article given above):

1. If the size of a BLOB item is several KB, it is included directly in row data. Consequently, even if you SELECT only non-BLOB columns, the engine still has to load all your BLOBs from disk. Say, you have 1M rows with 100 bytes of non-blob data each and 5000 bytes of blob data. You SELECT all non-blob columns and expect that MySQL would read from disk around 100-120 bytes per row, which is **100-120 MB** in total (+20 for BLOB address). However, the reality is that MySQL stores all BLOBs in the same disk blocks as rows, so they all must be read together *even if not used*, and so the size of data read from disk is around 5100 MB = **5 GB** - this is **50 times** more than you would expect and means **50 times slower** query execution.

   Of course, this design has an advantage: when you need all the columns, including the blob one, SELECT query is faster when blobs are stored with the row than when stored externally: you avoid (sometimes) 1 additional page access per row. However, this is not a typical use case for BLOBs and DB engine should not be optimized towards this case. If your data is so small that it fits in a row and you're fine with loading it in every query no matter if needed or not - then you would use VARCHAR type instead of BLOB/TEXT.
2. Even if for some reason (long row or long blob) the BLOB value is stored externally, its **768-byte prefix** is still kept in the row itself. Let's take the previous example: you have 100 bytes of non-blob data in each row, but now the blob column holds items of 1 MB each so they must be kept externally. SELECT of non-blob columns will have to read roughly 800 bytes per row (non-blobs + blob prefix), instead of 100-120 - this is again **7 times larger** disk transfer than you'd expect, and **7x slower** query execution.
3. External BLOB storage is ineffective in its usage of disk space: it allocates space in blocks of 16 KB and single block cannot hold multiple items, so if your blobs are small and take, for instance, 8 KB each, the actual space allocated is **twice** that large.

I hope this design will get fixed one day: MySQL will store ALL blobs - big and small - in external storage, without any prefixes kept in DB, with external storage allocation being efficient for items of all sizes. Before this happens, **separating out** BLOB/TEXT columns seems the only reasonable solution - separating out to another table or to the filesystem (each BLOB value kept as a file).

**[UPDATE 2019-10-15]**

InnoDB documentation provides now an ultimate answer to the issue discussed above:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-row-format.html

The case of storing 768-byte prefixes of BLOB/TEXT values inline holds indeed for **COMPACT** row format. According to the docs, "*For each non-NULL variable-length field (...) The internal part is 768 bytes*".

However, you can use **DYNAMIC** row format instead. With this format:

"*InnoDB can store long variable-length column values (...) **fully off-page**, with the clustered index record containing only a 20-byte pointer to the overflow page. (...) TEXT and BLOB columns that are less than or equal to 40 bytes are stored in line.*"

Here, a BLOB value can occupy **up to 40 bytes** of inline storage, which is much better than 768 bytes as in the COMPACT mode, and looks like a lot more reasonable approach in the case you want to mix BLOB and non-BLOB types in a table and still be able to scan multiple rows pretty fast. Moreover, the extended (over 20 bytes) inline storage is used ONLY for values sized between 20-40 bytes; for larger values, only the 20-byte pointer is stored (no prefix), unlike in the COMPACT mode. Hence, the extended 40-byte storage is used rarely in practice and one can safely assume the average size of inline storage to be just 20 bytes (or less, if you tend to keep many small values of less than 20B in your BLOB). All in all, it seems DYNAMIC row format, rather than COMPACT, should be the default choice in most cases to achieve good predictable performance of BLOB columns in InnoDB.

An example how to check the actual physical storage in InnoDB can be found here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210430/177276

As to **MyISAM**, it apparently **does NOT** provide off-page storage for BLOBs at all (just inline). Check here for more info:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/dynamic-format.html
- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,267596#msg-267596

Comment: **This is NOT TRUE, though** Wouldn't that be engine specific?  The main docs / code would only outline a few parameters the engine must fall within.  It looks like even for SQL Server putting `BLOB` inline can be questionable: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174678/why-is-it-recommended-to-store-blobs-in-separate-sql-server-tables  The ability to switch schemas (which database the table is in) alone seems worth it whenever data isn't stored outside of SQL entirely.

Comment: @DannieP these issues are not fixed - and I doubt they ever will be. Doing so would seriously affect backwards compatibility. The responsibility for storing BLOBs in a sensible way is placed on the user.

Comment: when using DYNAMIC mode should i still use a different table for my BLOB column?  or DYNAMIC solves this issue?

Comment: @amosguata I think DYNAMIC mostly solves the issue, only in very rare cases (when 20-40 bytes create a substantial overhead) you might still want to keep BLOBs in a separate table for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a composite index on the two relevant columns should allow these queries to be executed without accessing the table data directly.

```
CREATE INDEX `IX_score_status` ON `completed_tests` (`score`, `status`);
```

If you are able to switch to MariaDB then you can make the most of the table elimination optimisations.  This would allow you to split the BLOB field out into it's own table and use a view to recreate you existing table structure using a LEFT JOIN. This way it will only access the BLOB data if it is explicitly required for the executing query.

Comment: The composite index would help, but my actual query is much more complicated than the one I posted (joining more than one tables) so I was hoping for a solution that would target this problem. Nevertheless, I may focus on finding a suitable combination of indexes and query refactoring, I'll post here if something turns up.
About MariaDB, I hadn't heard of it, nice one (but not an option in my case unfortunately)
+1

Answer (score -1):

Just add index or indexes to fields used after WHERE query for a table with blobs.

e.g. You have 2 tables with those fields

```
users : USERID, NAME, ...
userphotos : BLOBID, BLOB, USERNO, ...

select * from userphotos where USERNO=123456;
```

Normaly this works fine. When you have many large images (e.g.  BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB more than 5GB in total ) this will take much time (more than minutes) while BLOBID is primary key.

Somehow MySQL is searching whole data including images if there is no index about the field of BLOB table in WHERE clause. When your data goes larger and larger that takes much time. If you create index for the field USERNO, this will speed up your database and it will be independed by the size of whole data.

**Solution:**

```
**Add Index to the USERNO at userphotos**
```

As an answer to your question you should create index for the ct.status