# Blob column needs to be moved to a different table for speed?

Tags: mysql

I have 30 columns in a table which will be frequently accessed. Out of 30 columns, 3 of the columns of type BLOB however it will be very rarely used.

Do we need to split the columns to different tables especially the blob?

We have some slowness but not sure whether it is due to having all blob columns in the same table.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: What are these BLOB sizes? and what is a record size except these fields?

Comment: Most sources suggest a separate table for blobs. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511476/speed-of-mysql-query-on-tables-containing-blob-depends-on-filesystem-cache) question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Cascader. That answers my question. Please put in answer's section so that i will mark it as resolved and helpful for many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Cascader

Most sources suggest a separate table for blobs.

Reference:

[Speed of mysql query on tables containing blob depends on filesystem cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511476/speed-of-mysql-query-on-tables-)
containing-blob-depends-on-filesystem-cache

Many people recommend using blob with only one primary key in a separate table and storing the blobs meta data in another table with a foreign key to the blob table. With this the performance will be higher considerably.